# regex для поиска атрибута без значения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, pcre

Привет всем!
у меня есть iframe который конвертуэться в xml например:

```
<iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

мне нужно составить регулярное выражение для поиска атрибутов типа allowfullscreen у которых нету значений ну и потом добавлять его например:

```
<iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

я пытался сделать регулярку но пока что у меня с ними туго подскажите:
<\w* .*\w(!?=)

Comment: Вы уверены, что парсить XML надо регуляркой? Может XML-парсер лучше для этого подойдет?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko не, это html который преобразовываеться в xml а при allowfullscreen без значения php выдает warning
Поетому перед тем как преобразовать в xml я обробляю html при помощи регулярки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю сварганить регулярку, которая будет править только одному атрибуту за раз, и применить её в цикле. Вероятно, это будет не самым эффективным подходом, зато результирующее выражение получится относительно простым.

Приведённый ниже код реализует эту идею. Чтобы была возможность прокомментировать регулярное выражение, использован расширенный синтаксис (обратите внимание на [модификатор `x`](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)). Для многострочного символьного литерала использован [heredoc синтаксис](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). В качестве второго аргумента функции **preg_filter** используется строка с [обратными ссылками](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php). Эта регулярка не обрабатывает ситуации, когда значения атрибутов не находятся внутри кавычек. Впрочем, при желании вам не составит труда добавить эту возможность.

```php
$tag_regex = <<<EOD
/(<                 # открывающий уголок
    \w+             # имя тега
    (?:
        \s*\w+      # имя нормального атрибута
        \s*=\s*     # разделяющий знак равенства
        "[^"]*"     # значение атрибута
    )*\s+
)
(\w+)               # текущий плохой атрибут
((?:\s+[^>]*)?>)    # остаток тега будет обработан позже
/x
EOD;

$markup = '<iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

for (;;) {
    $result = preg_filter($tag_regex, '$1$2="$2"$3', $markup, 1);
    if ($result === NULL) break;
    $markup = $result;
}

echo $markup;
```

<sup>Жаль, подсветка неверная :(</sup>

Пример работы - https://regex101.com/r/6FA44j/1

Comment: спасибо завтра буду тестить)

Comment: все работает, спасибо